# date-fns "RangeError: Invalid time value"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert 18:00:00.000 to 24H (18:00) and 12H (6PM) formats using date-fns. However, the input value of 18:00:00.000 gives a "RangeError: invalid time value".

My code

```
dateFns.format(new Date(18:00:00.000), 'H:mm')
```

I have no problem if I pass the time in the dateTime format such as 2022-01-04T11:00:00.000Z but I just need the time (hours and minutes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is failing because `new Date()` requires a valid date time string to create a new date object. To fix this, simply formulate a current date string and attach the timestamp you require and pass it to the `new Date()` method. Then you can pass the date object to the format method to get the desired output.

Refer to [this](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format) chart to format your dates as per your requirement.

```js
const now = dateFns.format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
const custTime = '18:00:00.000';
const custDt = new Date(`${now} ${custTime}`);
console.log(dateFns.format(custDt, 'h:mm A'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/2.0.0-alpha0/date_fns.min.js" integrity="sha512-0kon+2zxkK5yhflwFqaTaIhLVDKGVH0YH/jm8P8Bab/4EOgC/n7gWyy7WE4EXrfPOVDeNdaebiAng0nsfeFd9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```